# Laravel migration question about when should we use hasColumn function?

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-8

Good morning y'all!

I am facing some discussions at my workplace about laravel migrations, we do use laravel for backend and I started a comment on a code review about checking if the column exist, and only if does not exist we try to add a new column:

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::table('testing', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->boolean( 'boolean_test_value' )
              ->default( false )
              ->after('some_other_column' );
    });
}
```

And I am suggesting this as solution for it:

```
public function up(): void
{
    if (!Schema::hasColumn('testing', 'boolean_test_value')) {
       Schema::table('testing', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->boolean( 'boolean_test_value' )
                 ->default( false )
                 ->after('some_other_column' );
       });
   }
}
```

Can anyone explain why this can be a wrong thing to do? I am facing some replies that says this isn't recommended, I can't see why, is anyone with the same opinion could express why this isn't a good practice?

---

[UPDATE]

Let's show one situation:

- you have a new ticket to do
- this ticket is asking you to **re-create the whole database system** and figure it out a way to be the first one to run (if you have the name ordered as the first one, all new projects will run this first)
- you proceed without add any conditional

How can you **say migrations shouldn't have conditionals** if in this case we already have all the tables, and the proposal solution was add manually (avoiding it to run) to the migrations table?

Comment: Simple - with this check it will not throw error. But when you add migration - you want only two results - migration EXECUTED sucefully or error was thrown. Result “migration cannot be executed, but looks like succeful” - unwanted.

Comment: I also have one more thing to add @Maksim, one of the migrations that was missing the if conditional, was suggested to add the migration filename on migrations table as correct solution, do you agree with this?

Comment: Totally disagree, manually adding migration is disgusting.

Comment: The recommended approach is to create a new migration for each column modification or addition, regardless of whether the column already exists. This ensures your migrations are predictable, consistent, and easy to understand.

Comment: @KhayamKhan so are you in favour to have a new migration on the system and the migration shouldn't have any validation if exist or not a column? so how you fix the issue of the column already exist? as the proposal to add manually on migration table was the solution for this, with the same idea of: "create a new migration for each column modification or addition, regardless of whether the column already exists"

Comment: @JoseRafaelMendesBarbosa The recommended practice is indeed to create a new migration for each change to your database schema, regardless of whether the column already exists. However, this doesn't mean you should blindly create migrations without considering the current state of the schema. Instead, you should structure your migrations in a way that they can be applied safely and consistently across all environments.

Comment: with the conditional checks, it will have complex migration code, can lead to inconsistencies in your database schema across different environments (e.g., development, testing, production) if migrations are not run consistently

Comment: In summary, while creating new migrations for each change is generally a good practice, it's important to have a balance between being cautious about existing columns and maintaining a clean migration history. Checking for column existence before adding a new column is a sensible approach to avoid migration errors. It's all about finding a balance between maintaining a clean migration history and ensuring that your migrations can be applied safely and consistently across different environments.

Comment: Your second approach is totally not recommended because it doesn't make a sense. When you run the migration for first time, it'll be successful and laravel will remember the same and when running again the same migration will fail since laravel will report that the same column already exists. Which is why it make no sense as already beautiful explained in above comments.

Comment: Why would the column already exist?  If it exists an error should be thrown because it should not exist.

Comment: Hello @KhayamKhan, 


I do feel that add a conditional would be a solution, why? for all clients that are getting this now, wouldn't change a bit as they already have those tables. For all new projects that will run those migrations, this case was added as first migration, so if we check if exist any table would return false, so we could always see this working for both cases, but i still am getting replies saying that we shouldn't do this.

Comment: Hello @KhayamKhan, for a specific columns, i could only see an issue with checking if a column exist, if you are changing/updating something of a column, but if you are adding it, isn't a issue to check if exist the column, so as you are creating a new column shouldn't exist this, so isn't an issue to check before it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the `hasColumn` check in some rare occasions.

First of all the meaning of migrations are to run smoothly and create your database structure as it should. Migrations should be depended on each other and have a "flow" and by that i mean that in your example the `some_other_column` is supposed to have been created in a previous migration otherwise the migration will throw an error as it should.

So normally in a project when you run your migrations they should be already in place all the columns and everything without having to check them, otherwise you must allow errors to happen so you can fix. In this case if for any reason the `testing` column is created you will get a "free pass" from the migration but is it really what you want? Why would this column not have been create already in a previous migration? Was it necessary to happen?

In my prio experience i remember very limited edge cases where the backend was deployed in multiple environments. Every environment of course had it's own .env file etc etc. One of the requests was that "we want column X in environment ENV_1, but this column should not appear in the other environments". The project specs was that each environment had it's own database and generally it was completely stand alone. But the problem was that the backend was the same of course so the Backend had to treat each environment with it's own "unique" things.

So it was the only way to have checks and one of them was using the `hasColumn` to ensure that if that column exists then run the migration, you get the main idea.

In a well structured project you don't have to ensure that columns are there, instead you want to see if a migration fails the reason it failed.

For edge cases well that's another story but i would definitely not call it a good practise to have checks like this in migrations. If a migration is throwing an error, the error should be fixed not bypassed.

**Answer update:**

I had faced before a similar issue based on the one you described on the comment, there was a project with a database already set but very old legacy system that my team migrated to laravel.

Long story short for XYZ reason the database was not to be touched. The best approach since you have already build your migrations would be to make a seeder to run one time and seed the migrations into the migrations table. It will be an one-time thing and migrations are basically the file names of the migration so you read all the file names in there until name whatever and you just hit mass insert.

A seeder to run 1 time and save you all the hustle. If the seeders are running through your pipelines in every deployment you should use `updateOrCreate` method so you don't mess up any migrations.

After that you don't have to check if the column exists in your new migrations.

Comment: Hello @pr1nc3! 

I want to focus on this part of your reply:



"Why would this column not have been create already in a previous migration? Was it necessary to happen?"

1 - let say we have a ticket to rebuild the whole database using one migration table as the first one
2 - we already have a database set with all tables
3 - the solution was asked to add on migrations table the name of this new content added to develop branch to the migrations table, so would avoid it (this part i do feel too much manual work, that an if could fix for all environments, no?)

Comment: "In a well structured project you don't have to ensure that columns are there, instead you want to see if a migration fails the reason it failed."

A: I just told you in a previous comment that one of the tickets were to ensure to have the database structure (after we have all things done, so all tables and structures are there already). Sounds a little bit off timing, if was done only right things all the time, wouldn't be a solution to add manually to the migrations table, correct? so we need to think a little bit different from the normal flow of the things no?

Comment: If i understand correctly, you have a database that did not use migrations so what you are trying to do is to build all the migrations now and have them run in a database that exists already so you will be able to generate the current database structure through migrations right? But if you actually try to run those migrations in the existing database since the tables/columns exist already and the migrations are considered "new" since they don't exist in the migrations table, the migrations will fail. Am i getting it right?

Comment: You are getting right, we already have the table structure and we will be adding a new migration on the project, so what should be the correct action on this?

* add manually the migration  on the migration table?
or 
* add the conditional?

Note: if you have a better way to do it, please let me know.

Comment: I had faced before a similar thing, there was a project with a database already set but very old legacy system that my team migrated to laravel. Long story short for XYZ reason the database was not to be touched. The best approach since you have already build your migrations would be to make a seeder to run one time and seed the migrations into the migrations table. It will be an one-time thing and migrations are basically the file names of the migration so you read all the file names in there until name whatever and you just hit mass insert. A seeder to run 1 time and save you all the hustle.

Comment: Create another migration file to add add/drop/modify column that you wish without worrying of checking if the column exists or not.

Comment: @OMiShah hello! I think the issue that i am trying to share is, when we have already a colum/table and we are trying to re-create the same thing, should I validate with a hasColumn or hasTable before run any new migration that the proposed solution is to add manually the name of it on the migrations table. What whould be the best approach? yours is asking to remove/modify a column, so in my case if this was the correct thing to do, i would need just for one case to delete the whole database, as was re-build the whole structure by using a migration file that i had to add manually on database.

Comment: @JoseRafaelMendesBarbosa, got it. Sine you have manually added the table. Now you have two option, you can check using the hasColumn or hasTable method as you have planned or else you can manually add the migration files names to the migration table manually after which on running migration will skip the migration files for which you manually added table/columns. Your choice.

Comment: I updated my answer as well attaching the comment i sent in our previous discussion here so it is more complete with some additional info.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check if the table has a duplicate column you are already doing something wrong. If the column exists you WANT that migration to fail, not be ignored.

**Update for when you inherit an old database not built on Laravel**

In this case I would recommend to **NOT** use migrations at all. At least not to try to rebuild the DB. Migrations are not meant to be used like that. No amount of "*if column exists*" will 100% verify that you have not forgotten a column, constraint, index or whatever. You can continue to use them for changes to your DB tho.

Instead I would recommend to use a schema dump, by running `php artisan schema:dump`. Now if you are just setting up your project and no migration has been run, Laravel will run your schema dump **FIRST** and only after that will it run migrations. Again these migrations should only include changes to your DB, not try to rebuild it.

Docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#squashing-migrations

Comment: So let's try make you understand what is the situation, maybe i wasn't clear enough. So imagine that someone asked you, can you re-create the whole database structure, as first migration to run, and this is a ticket. So you write a file that re-creates it the whole database, and you do not do any check on it, you just assume that everything wouldn't exist, and propose the solution to avoid this file for all other clients asking you to add manually on each database as solution for this instead of using an if conditional for it.

Comment: I updated the answer, but you already having the DB is a very important detail you should have mentioned in your question, not on some comment @JoseRafaelMendesBarbosa